# Does the PHP function get called every time you use a variable?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, performance, function

Not sure if this is the place to ask. Here is my code and my question is after the code:

```
function test() {
    $db->SELECT * FROM... etc...

    $array = array("Car"=>$row['car'], "Boat"=>$row['boat'], "Plane"=>$row['plane']);
    return $array;
}

$vehicles = test();

echo $vehicles['car']; // call 1
echo $vehicles['boat']; // call 2
echo $vehicles['plan']; // call 3
```

as you can see, i call `$vehicles[];` 3 times. Every time it calls the `$vehicles`, does it need to go back to the `test()` function and search through the database on every call? Or does it store the array in the `$vehicles` variable once on page load? thanks.

Comment: NO it will not call the method three times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is called once. The call to the `$vehicles` variable will pull the content from the array stored, not the function.

So the test()-function is only run once (on page load).

Answer (score 2):

No. `test()` is executed once, and the return variable (Which is an array) is assigned to `$vechicles`.

I've created a test [here](https://eval.in/780562), which shows how this functionality works:

```
<?php

function test() {
    echo 'Test function called', "\n";

    $array = array("Car"=> 'Test car', "Boat"=> 'Test boat', "Plane"=> 'Test plane');
    return $array;
}

$vehicles = test();

echo $vehicles['Car'], "\n"; // call 1
echo $vehicles['Boat'], "\n"; // call 2
echo $vehicles['Plane'], "\n"; // call 3
```

You'll notice that "Test function called" is only echoed out once (At the beginning). If this function was called multiple times, "Test function called" would be echoed multiple times.